# Qual tamanho usar para modelos 3d importados no Unity 3D?

Tags: unity3d, model, 3d, game

Estou começando um novo projeto no Unity 3D usando modelos 3d gratuitos da internet, importei um prédio mas quando fui abrir no Unity estava gigantesco comparado ao personagem padrão do Unity!
Minha duvida é se eu devo diminuir o prédio ou aumentar o personagem, e se há algum problema com isso, e alguma dica se alguem puder dar!

Comment: O idioma do site é português, traduza sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

O melhor será redimensionar o seu prédio à escala da personagem, sendo que esta vem pré-feita pelo Unity, é sempre bom manter as coisas niveladas, mas acaba por ser irrelevante! Sendo novo em Unity, recomendo-lhe que assista este fantástico youtuber, fácil e eficaz. [Brackeys](https://www.youtube.com/user/Brackeys)